# Customize right click context menu in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp

How can I add a new item to right click menu for any file type and associate a action to this without using any third party tool. I hope it is possible using some registry hack..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the following into a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MakeSomethingUp]
@="This text will appear in the context menu"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MakeSomethingUp\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Import that file into the Registry.

Does that do what you need?

Comment: yes.. this works great. One more thing how can I control the sequencing of this newly added item?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to manipulate the order of context menu items, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/13596/how-do-i-add-an-item-to-the-right-click-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen for any file type, and you're just passing the file as an arg to the program in question, you can put a shortcut to the program in your SendTo menu (at %userprofile%\SendTo).  I keep Notepad and Wordpad in there all the time.